# fill color inside <td> and export diagram to excel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanna fill in color in  like what present in the picture,which is part of table.The width and position of black square can be calculated according to the data in the other part of table I do not attach below.

[image]

I wanna put a `<span>` inside the `<td>` to generate the black square.

The code is:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="8" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">...</th>
      <th colspan="16" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">...</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      <th></th>
      .......
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><span> </span></td>
    </tr>
    .......
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  $("table tr:eq(2) td:eq(6) span").css({
    "display": "block",
    "background-color": "black",
    "height": "$(this).parent().css('height')",
    "width": "50%",
    "left": "0",
    "right": "50%",
  });
</script>
```

But it does not work, black square do not been presented.How to solve this problem? And Besides, the table must be exported to excel including the black square,I know how to deal with text, but diagram to excel...I have no idea

[image]

This function can be realised by narrowing the width of every column in Excel,but i do not how to realise with code

Comment: I don't know how well excel will handle partially filled cells.

Comment: Excel can work ,you can refer to the image I attached just now

Comment: How are you exporting to excel? That is important as excel has no concept of a `span` most exports is a 1 to 1 export when it comes to cells.

Comment: So this function can not be realised by javascript ? I just want to realise this function , no matter what technology is used.

Comment: In fact,it is 1 to 1 export.For example, actually,row "16" occupy 4 cells and black square occupy 1 cell.Although it looks like ,black square is realised by filling 1/4 of the cell,the fact is not.But I do not know how to realise in code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding content to your span in terms of a `&nbsp;` fixes your immediate problem.

```js
$("table tr:eq(2) td:eq(6) span").css({
    "display": "block",
    "background-color": "black",
    "height": "$(this).parent().css('height')",
    "width": "50%",
    "left": "0",
    "right": "50%",
  });
```

```css
td {border: black 1px solid;padding:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="8" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">...</th>
      <th colspan="16" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">...</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      <th></th>
      .......
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

As I mentioned in the comment, I don't see this working with excel exporting.

Comment: I find a solution ,but in excel the width of cell is hard to control